# Card Deck with Unicode Suits

Tags: c++, unicode, struct

I have created a deck of cards to use for a Black Jack and Poker Game. I used a struct to make the properties of the cards defined as such:

```
struct ACard{
int num;
char pic[4];
};
```

I need to set the `pic` as a the suit of each card.
I have been given the Unicode for each such suit:

♠ = `\xe2\x99\xa0`

♣ = `\xe2\x99\xa3`

❤ = `\xe2\x99\xa5`

♦ = `\xe2\x99\xa6`

I have created a constant variable for each of the four suits like so:

```
const char spade[4] = "\xe2\x99\xa0";
const char club[4] = "\xe2\x99\xa3";
const char heart[4] = "\xe2\x99\xa5";
const char diamond[4] = "\xe2\x99\xa6";
```

When initiate the the card class I set the value of each card Ace - King (1-13) like so:

```
deck::deck(){

//Creating the Spade Cards (A-K)

for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++){    //Start loop
    cards[i].num = i + 1;
    //cards[i].pic = spade;
}               //End loop


//Creating the Club Cards (A-K)

for(int i = 13; i < 27; i++){   //Start loop
    cards[i].num = i -12;
    //cards[i].pic = club;
}               //End loop


//Creating the Heart Cards (A-K)

for(int i = 26; i < 40; i++){   //Start loop
    cards[i].num = i-25;    
    //cards[i].pic = heart;
}

//Creating the Diamond Cards (A-K)

for(int i = 39; i < 52; i++){   //Start loop
    cards[i].num = i - 38;
    //cards[i].pic = diamond;
}               //End loop


nextCard = 0;
```

}

As you can see I try to set the `pic` of each card to each card, but that doesn't work. How would I set each pic in the struct to the correct unicode?

Comment: Use an enum to represent the suit.  What it should look like on the screen is an implementation detail that has nothing to do with your game data and logic.  And is trivially implemented when you display a hand of cards.  Separating the model and the view is a standard programming technique.

Comment: Actually, you may change your struct to `struct ACard { int num; char *pic; };`. Is it not necessary to copy your strings as they are constant. Thus, you may assign the address of the resp. string to `ACard::pic` e.g. `ACard aCard; aCard.pic = spade;` Btw. this is even a tiny bit faster than `memcpy()` and safes memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

struct ACard{
    int num;
    const char* pic;

    ACard(int _num, const char* _pic) : num{_num}, pic{_pic}
    {
    }
};

const char spade[4] = "\xe2\x99\xa0";
const char club[4] = "\xe2\x99\xa3";
const char heart[4] = "\xe2\x99\xa5";
const char diamond[4] = "\xe2\x99\xa6";

int main()
{
    ACard AceSpades = ACard(12, spade);

    std::cout << "Ace of spades: " << AceSpades.num << " " << AceSpades.pic << std::endl;
}
```

This way you aren't unnecessarily copying the constant char array.

Answer (score 0):

Use memcpy, for example:

```
memcpy(cards[i].pic, spade, 4);
```

Comment: Do you have a concrete objection against using memcpy in this case?

Comment: Actually, I suggested to use neither nor. And actually, I count the hint in the comment of Hans Passant as best...